# Passing data into a function expression

Tags: javascript, tdd

I'm a relative JS newbie, and am uncertain I am using the proper terminology when asking this question.

I'm working through some JS coding exercises, and this particular one requires a function that tests whether a year is a leap year.

```
var Year = function() {};

Year.prototype.isLeap = function(input) {
  if((input % 4 === 0) && (input % 100 !== 0)){
    return true;
  }
};
```

The function itself is not the issue for me, it is writing it in the specific way to pass the given test:

```
describe('Leap year', function() {

  it('is not very common', function() {
    var year = new Year(2015);
    expect(year.isLeap()).toBe(false);
  });
```

As my code is written, it seems input is undefined, how can I pass it in by calling `new Year(2015);` ?

Comment: Pass the value to the function and not to the constructor and it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are seeking to use `new Year(2015)`, then I would suggest the following:

```
var Year = function(year) {
  this.year = year;
};

Year.prototype.isLeap = function() {
  return this.year % 4 === 0 && this.year % 100 !== 0;
};

describe('Leap year', function() {
  it('is not very common', function() {
    var year = new Year(2015);
    expect(year.isLeap()).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

Here, we are taking advantage of the pseudoclassical instantiation style, where the `Year` constructor function accepts a parameter, which is then saved on `this` (which is an empty object before `this.year = year` is executed). Then, since the `isLeap()` method is called by an instance of `Year` (aka an object with a `year` property), the `isLeap()` method will be able to access that `year` property via `this.year`.

Comment: Thank you very much, @therobinkim